# PrimeFaces on selectCheckboxMenu click inside h:panelGrid causes page jump to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` component inside `<h:panelGrid>` as you can see in example :

```
    <h:panelGroup id="....">
        <p:fieldset id="....."
                    rendered="#{...}">

            <app:formInputTextarea/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="1">

                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="temp-id"
                                          value="#{someTabView.someCodes}"
                                          label="...."
                                          panelStyle="width:270px"
                                          styleClass="ui-chkbxmenu" filter="true"
                                          filterMatchMode="contains" caseSensitive="false">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{someMainCodes}" var="tempCode"
                                       itemValue="#{tempCode}"
                                       itemLabel="#{.....}"/>
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

                    <app:formCheckBox/>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:outputLabel value= "#{......}"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="......"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is when I click on `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` page jumps to top but only if:

1. Using Chrome (on other browsers works fine)
2. Browser opened on "big screen" - PC monitor (on laptop works fine)
3. Page is scrolled to page bottom

Also problem occurs in another place in different page with same conditions:

```
<h:panelGroup id="...."
                          rendered="#{(....)}"
                          layout="block"
                          style="width: 50%">
                <h:panelGroup>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass=".....">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg[......']}"/>
                                <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="......."
                                                      label="#{msg['........']}"
                                                      value="#{.........}"
                                                      filter="true"
                                                      filterMatchMode="contains"
                                                      caseSensitive="false"
                                                      styleClass="ui-chkbxmenu">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{.......}"
                                                   var="......."
                                                   itemValue="#{......}"
                                                   itemLabel="#{.......}"
                                                   itemDisabled="#{.........}"/>
                                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                </h:panelGroup>
```

I don't know if it helps but only thing that I was able to find in first case if you take out the `<h:panelGrid>` columns="3"> jump is gone but the structure "breaks" and considering that second case is not the same as first I don't think that that it might be a problem causer. 
Also doing debugging I found out that after click event there is function trigger call which makes object to be focused and after return page jump happens! 
[jqueryDebugFunctionImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE3cz.png)

Does any one have any idea why is that ? Maybe page does not match html standard...? I'm not hoping that somebody is gonna resolve this problem (I know there might be so many things that can cause this kinda bug) but get at least some ideas witch way I need to look or how to debug this properly. Thanks!

Comment: Primefaces version? You're using really many nested panels grid, are you sure you can't use only one, managing row and col span (since you say that resolve the scroll behavior)? Or start from only the checkbox and then add all the other components, one by one, till you get some problem/strange behavior.

Comment: I concur with @WoAiNii start pulling things out one at a time/ Another problem i see is how can you use p:column and p:row when not inside an PrimeFaces component. You know those tags won't work in an `h:panelGroup` right?

Comment: Yes, using colspan or rowspan if needed